# Postfix is using port 25 when I have specified it to use 587

Tags: ubuntu

I run Ubuntu 18.04 on an AWS/EC2 instance.  I have installed mailutils and postfix in hopes of making a send-only mail server.

I have read that several providers block port 25 as a means of preventing spam, which is fine.  I was attempting to avoid this problem by forcing Postfix to send on port 587 instead of port 25.  After careful setup & troubleshooting, all of my attempts to send test-emails on the command line end up as "connection timed out" and show the attempted connection on the recipient mail-server's port 25.

Here a portion of my master.cf, I have only made one change on TWO lines.  The first is where I made an entry for 587, and the second where I commented out the entry for smtp

```
# ==========================================================================
587        inet n - - - - smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

*I have redacted the ip-address and hostnames for privacy*

This is a portion of my main.cf file.  I have only changed one setting on inet_interfaces to "loopback-only"

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = REDACTED.ca-central-1.compute.internal
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = REDACTED
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

I have restarted and reloaded postfix with these configuration changes.  On the command line I've tried the following command for three different email recipients:

> ubuntu@REDACTED:/etc/postfix$ echo "Hello David" | mail -s "Here is your invoice bro" -a "FROM:david@HOSTNAME_REDACTED.ca" contact@REDACTED.ca

I've tried this command where I change the last parameter to two other email addresses.  In my mail queue:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-145:/etc/postfix$ mailq
-Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
AB9ED47F37      424 Fri Apr  9 02:50:00  david@REDACTED.ca
(connect to msn-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.58.33]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         (email1@provider1.com)

D366F47F48      435 Fri Apr  9 03:31:10  david@REDACTED.ca
  (connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.186.27]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         (email3@provider3.ca)

3E5F847F3D      434 Fri Apr  9 02:58:38  david@REDACTED.ca
(connect to msn-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.55.161]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         (email1@provider1.com)

4EF7E47F46      434 Fri Apr  9 03:14:01  david@REDACTED.ca
(connect to myumanitoba-ca.mail.protection.outlook.com[104.47.60.36]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         (email2@provider2.ca)

4926247F2D      424 Fri Apr  9 02:36:11  david@REDACTED.ca
(connect to msn-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.12.33]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         (email1@provider1.com)

4516047F34      434 Fri Apr  9 02:56:55  david@REDACTED.ca
(connect to msn-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.8.33]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         (email1@provider1.com)

9B09347F32      424 Fri Apr  9 02:44:32  david@REDACTED.ca
(connect to msn-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.9.33]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         (email1@provider1.com)

-- 2 Kbytes in 7 Requests.
```

As shown in each of those messages, it's attempting to connect on :25 to the recipient server, shouldn't this be 587?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The postfix documentation doesn't go into any depth with port numbers and I'm seriously lost.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you configured postfix to listen on port 587 only. You need to configure it to send email on that port.

Try:

```
relayhost = [relayhost_ip]:587
```

on main.cf